# Understanding the regexp in ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)" used in split

Tags: java, regex, split

While doing a Java course, I've come across this code:

`String[] columns = row.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");`

Checking the [documentation of the split method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) we can understand that between parenthesis there's a regexp string.

Checking the [documentation of regexp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), things become more tricky:

Splitting the expression into the pieces I find in [the said documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) :

1. `,` - The character we expect the string to be divided with
2. `(` - closes at point 16
3. `?=` - (?=X)    X, via zero-width positive lookahead
4. `(` - closes at point 11
5. `[^\"]` - Any character except «*"*»
6. `*` - I don't get this
7. `\"` - The character «*"*»
8. `[^\"]` - Again, like in point 5, any character except «*"*»
9. `*` - Again, like in point 6, I'm not sure I get this
10. `\"` - Again, like in point 7, the character «*"*»
11. `)` - Closes expression started at point 4
12. `*` - Is this some kind of logical AND ?
13. `[^\"]` - Like in points 5 and 8, any character except «*"*»
14. `*` - Same as points 6, 9 and 12
15. `$` - Boundary matcher indicating the end of a line
16. `)` - Closes expression started at point 2

I don't understand right from point 3, as I don't understand what is a *lookahead*. I was able to get a gist of it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3481842/5790245), that uses [this website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as a reference, where we can read about positive and negative lookaheads:

> Negative lookahead is indispensable **if you want to match something not followed by something else**. When explaining character classes, this tutorial explained why you cannot use a negated character class to match a q not followed by a u. Negative lookahead provides the solution: q(?!u). The negative lookahead construct is the pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an exclamation point. Inside the lookahead, we have the trivial regex u.
>
> **Positive lookahead works just the same. q(?=u) matches a q that is followed by a u, *without making the u part of the match*.** The positive lookahead construct is a pair of parentheses, with the opening parenthesis followed by a question mark and an equals sign.
>
> You can use any regular expression inside the lookahead (but not lookbehind, as explained below). Any valid regular expression can be used inside the lookahead.

Ok, so now that point 3 is *kind* of understood, what I got so far is that we are trying to split the string with the character «,» (point 1), followed by the expression `([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$`.

At this point I'm led to believe that the question has become: **How does * agglutinates expressions in a regexp in Java ?**

Looking into the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) I find three instances of it, but I still don't get it:

- In Greedy quantifiers, X*    X, zero or more times;
- In Reluctant quantifiers, X*?    X, zero or more times
- In Possessive quantifiers, X*+   X, zero or more times

Please correct me if I any of the deductions is wrong, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Read this? https://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-are-differences-among-greedy-reluctant-and-possessive-quantifiers-in-java-patterns/206

Comment: Try pasting the regex [here](https://regex101.com/) and read the explanation

Comment: The meaning of `*` in regex is very basic and should be covered in the most fundamental introductions. It allows for the repetition of the previous expression zero or more times.

Comment: Everything is explained very well at http://regular-expressions.info and http://rexegg.com. Links available in the linked thread.

Comment: In so many words, require there to be an even number of `"` after the separator. In other words, don't split between two `"`:s. (Still probably broken for some dialects of CSV, if that's what you are attempting to split.)

Comment: Well, the regex split on comma which is not contained in a string, but this is a rather piss poor approach if the purpose is to parse CSV